# Advanced Active Record order by using regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I am trying to query my Order model for all records but I want them ordered in a very specific way.

Database is a PostgreSQL database.

I want all records that start with `NY` first, `NYN` next, then all remaining records follow.

I think I'm trying to do something like this:

```
Order.all.order('order_number /^NY/, /^NYN/')
```

An example of data:

```
NY-1111111
NYN-1234567
P-000000
P0000000
SS0232131
NYN16151202
```

The order I want is:

```
NY-1111111
NYN16151202
NYN-1234567
P0000000
P-000000
SS0232131
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way you might do this in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM orders
  ORDER BY
    CASE
      WHEN order_number LIKE 'NYN%' THEN 1
      WHEN order_number LIKE 'NY%' THEN 0
      ELSE 2
    END,
    order_number;
```

This can be translated pretty directly to an ActiveRecord query:

```ruby
Order.order("
  CASE
    WHEN order_number LIKE 'NYN%' THEN 1
    WHEN order_number LIKE 'NY%' THEN 0
    ELSE 2
  END,
  order_number
")
```

Here's another possibility using PostgreSQL's POSIX regular expressions. I'm not sure how it compares to the above in performance:

```
Order.order("
  CASE SUBSTRING(order_number FROM '^NYN?')
    WHEN 'NY' THEN 0
    WHEN 'NYN' THEN 1
    ELSE 2
  END,
  order_number
")
```

Comment: plus 1 .. really nice and efficient answer : )

Comment: Efficient *and* correct. That second part is sometimes sort of important ;)

Comment: fantastic @jordan. thank you very much. This is much more efficient and works perfect.

Comment: Glad to help. I've added a second solution to my answer. If you have a large data set I'd be curious which performs better.

Comment: @VinnyAlfieri I've edited my answer because I realized I had the NY/NYN order backwards (I was putting "NYN" first). Also, just FYI I just noticed that in your example you have "NYN16..." before "NYN-12..." and "PP00..." before "PP-00...", which my answer doesn't address.

Comment: Thanks @jordan, I was able to figure out the edge cases my self based on your solution. Appreciate the help!! Happy coding!!! <3

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by ruby sort_by method like this:

```
orders = Order.all.sort_by{ | order |
    if order.name =~ /^NYN/
        -1;
    elsif order.name =~ /^NY/
        -2;
    else
        0;
    end
}
```

So if order names are : `["ghi", "NYabc", "jk", "NYNdef"]`, the order would be: `["NYabc", "NYNdef", "ghi", "jk"]` or `["NYabc", "NYNdef", "jk", "ghi"]`

You can find the documentation of sort_by [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Array.html#method-i-sort_by)

Hope it helps : )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is super close to what I am trying to get going. My issue now is that I need the return value to be an ActiveRecord object rather than an array which is why I wanted to try and complete the query using ActiveRecord queries.

Comment: @VinnyAlfieri Welcome .. Am Glad that it helped : )

Comment: This is terribly inefficient. You're pulling all of the records from the database, sorting them in Ruby, and then pulling all of the records from the database *again*. There's no reason not to do the sorting in your query and only fetch the records once.

Comment: @jordan if you have any clues on how to do it inside of one query, i'd appreciate it.

Comment: @VinnyAlfieri Please edit/tag your question to indicate what database system you're using (MySQL, PostgreSQL, whathaveyou).

Comment: Thanks @jordan. it is a PostgreSQL database.

Comment: @Jordan Yes you are right, I would also appreciate, if you can make SQL query for it..

Comment: Are you sure that `Order.find([1,2,3])` is guaranteed to return the models in the `1,2,3` order? And why refetch them if you already have them?

Comment: @muistooshort no it doesnt! I will update/remove the later part. Thanks for the mention. Anways, I feel that second answer is more appropriate. btw, refetching was because the he wanted the output not be Array by Active Record ...